# How to tell when all threads are complete when they are recursively created?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, recursion

**Introduction**
Currently I have a subroutine that I need to call recursively. I am calling it in a separate thread each time I need it. For example:

```
Private Sub process_part_for_tkv(ByVal a As String, ByVal b As Integer, ByVal c As Integer, ByVal d As String)

'Do stuff
For Loop 'sudo code just to show a loop is used

   Dim process_part_for_tkv_thread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() process_part_for_tkv(newa, newb, newc, newd))
   process_part_for_tkv_thread.IsBackground = True
   process_part_for_tkv_thread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
   process_part_for_tkv_thread.Start()    
Next

End Sub
```

I would then call the initial sub to run using this:

```
   Dim process_part_for_tkv_thread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() process_part_for_tkv(newa, newb, newc, newd))
   process_part_for_tkv_thread.IsBackground = True
   process_part_for_tkv_thread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
   process_part_for_tkv_thread.Start()
```

**Question**

The threads work all fine but how can I tell when all of my threads are done running? Is there a way to track this?

Comment: You need some sort of list to keep track of them. I'm curious, how many thread do you have when this runs? To many isn't going to speed things up.

Comment: Well the threads themselves are relatively small and quick being why I want to run them in parallel. I would guess around 1000 or so total but most are closed very quickly so not many running at once

Comment: So when I create a new thread, how do I add it to a list?

Comment: `yourList.Add(process_part_for_tkv_thread)`.

Comment: Why are you building raw threads instead of using eg `Parallel.For` or tasks? It's a *lot* easier to track and await tasks. Besides, having 100 threads will just waste electricity if you only have 4 cores and CPU-bound jobs. Instead of calculating, the cores will waste time switching from one sleeping thread to another. `Parallel.For/ForEach` though checks the number of cores and items and only uses as many threads as needed to ensure maximum throughput and minimum overhead

Comment: At the very least you should be using the `ThreadPool` threads, not raw threads. `Parallel.For` is really the correct way to go here though.  What you are doing now is going to seriously over-saturate your CPU with threads

Comment: Like Panagiotis said. If it's a CPU task, it's pointless to have more threads than the number of cpu core. You can look at the status of all thread or set a flag when the function ends.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess I am new to threading then. Are there some good examples out there for using Parallel.For?

Comment: A *lot*. Just try googling for `Parallel.For`. You should also try to understand about data parallelism. There is no point in trying to work in parallel if one computation requires the results of another. `Parallel.For` will take a collection and apply an operation to each element. Obviously, this works best if they calculations aren't related in any way.

Comment: Parallel summation on the other hand requires the intermediate results. In this case, `Parallel.Sum` wil split the data across all cores (roughly), create intermediate sums then collect them to one sum as a last step. Same for `Parallel.Min`, Max, etc.

Comment: Well correct me if I am wrong but since my tasks are dependent of each other, I don't think Parallel.For will work will it? I need to feed the results into each other

Comment: @BradleyUffner The thread pool method seems to be a good option for what I am trying to do. What is the best way to know if all the queued items in the pool are completed?

Comment: I would recommend Tasks. It´s very easy to implement them. E.g. check [Task.WhenAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)